# PHP Not Receiving AJAX Post Data, When AJAX is sending correctly

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I am using the following AJAX to make a call to a PHP function:

```
 $.ajax({
    url : 'php/jstranslator.php',
    type : 'post',
    data : {'action' : 'campaignnamecheck',
           'newcampaignname' : campaignname,
           'oldcampaignname' : oldcampaignname },
    success : function(result) {
        check = result;
        console.log("campaignnamecheck: " + check);
    },
    error : function(xhr, desc, err) {
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
    }
});
```

The php receiving this call looks like this:

```
if ($_POST['action'] == "campaignnamecheck") {
    $newcampaignname = $_POST['newcampaignname'];
    $oldcampaignname = $_POST['oldcampaignname'];

    campaignnamecheck($newcampaignname, 
                      $oldcampaignname);

}
```

And the campaignnamecheck function looks like this:

```
function campaignnamecheck($newcampaignname, $oldcampaignname) {
    $conn = conn();
    echo "php oldcampaignname: " . $oldcampaignname;
    // Select any campaigns 
    $campaignsql = "SELECT CampaignName " .
        "FROM campaignstest " .
        "WHERE CampaignName = '" . $newcampaignname . "' ";
    if(!$campaignresult = $conn->query($campaignsql)){
        die('There was an error running the query "' . $campaignsql . '" [' . $conn->error . ']');
    }

    // If the campaign name remained the same as before it is a safe campaign name
    if ($newcampaignname == $oldcampaignname) {
    } else {
        // If the campaign name changed, or if it's a new campaign, then check to see if the name already exists in the database
        if ($campaignresult->num_rows == 0) {
            echo "true";
        } else {
            echo "false";
        }
    }
}
```

The error I am receiving in my apache error log is as follows:

```
[Wed Mar 07 16:30:00.330318 2018] [:error] PHP Warning:  Missing argument 2 for campaignnamecheck(), called in /var/www/html/test/php/jstranslator.php on line 110 and defined in /var/www/html/test/php/campaignsfuncs.php on line 747
[Wed Mar 07 16:30:00.330779 2018] [:error] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: oldcampaignname in /var/www/html/test/php/campaignsfuncs.php on line 749
```

When I look in the network tab of the console on chrome I can see that the values you have been set:

```
action:campaignnamecheck
newcampaignname:test
oldcampaignname:none
```

What on earth am I missing?

Comment: Have you check the posts being sent to your page? like this: `if ($_POST['action'] == "campaignnamecheck") {
    $newcampaignname = $_POST['newcampaignname'];
    $oldcampaignname = $_POST['oldcampaignname'];
if(!empty($newcampaignname) && !empty($oldcampaignname))
    campaignnamecheck($newcampaignname, 
                      $oldcampaignname);

}`

Comment: Is the code you provided above actually from line 110? "/var/www/html/test/php/jstranslator.php on line 110" ... kind of baffling how it wouldn't be passed, given its set right above being called.

Comment: I suggest you just do a `var_dump($oldcampaignname);` right after `$oldcampaignname = $_POST['oldcampaignname'];` to see if it actually is set or not. If yes, then right after `$conn = conn();` do the same thing. It will help you figure out where the issue is coming from.

Comment: Even if the post var is empty (or even missing, and if missing there would be an error for `Notice: Undefined index:`, which there is not, so the post var ***must exist***)... doing `$oldcampaignname = $_POST['oldcampaignname'];` would have set `$oldcampaignname` regardless. So the use of it in the function call *right under it* should have passed something, as it would be a second argument. Even if you set it to null... its passing an argument and would not cause that error.

Comment: Yes, that's correct but i believe we missing some code.

Comment: Yes, I believe so too. I don't think what he/she pasted above is from around line 110 :(

Comment: The line: $oldcampaignname = $_POST['oldcampaignname']; is line 110.

Comment: @RensTillmann, when adding vardump statement after $oldcampaignname = $_POST['oldcampaignname']; it seems to magically work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no clude why this fixed my problem. But for debugging I added a line:

```
if ($_POST['action'] == "campaignnamecheck") {
    $newcampaignname = $_POST['newcampaignname'];
    $oldcampaignname = $_POST['oldcampaignname'];
    var_dump($oldcampaignname);

    campaignnamecheck($newcampaignname, 
                      $oldcampaignname);

}
```

and now it seems to be working.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense though have you also test the same on a different environment? I mean yeah code might work, but would be nice to find out the real reason / cause of this behavior not? And what did `var_dump` output?

Comment: No It was all on the same environment. It output string(4) none just like it should

Comment: Yes, but have you tested it on different environment i meant. Just to determine where this cause is coming from. Could be even memory issue. I would have no other clue of why it would happen...

Answer (score -1):

So i think its obvious. Somehow you are not passing the second parameter to `campaignnamecheck()`. means you have not received it from `$_POST`.

```
if ($_POST['action'] == "campaignnamecheck") {
  $newcampaignname = $_POST['newcampaignname'];
  $oldcampaignname = $_POST['oldcampaignname'];
  if(!empty($newcampaignname) && !empty($oldcampaignname)) {
     campaignnamecheck($newcampaignname, $oldcampaignname); 
  }
}
```

First of all when you write code you need to check if values are suitable with ifs or try catch statements.

And also debugging your code is an essential skill